# how to set video recorder

Tags: video, record, coded-ui-tests

i checked the video recorder in the test setting for recording the automatic test
in the end of the test i got an error in test result "video recording cannot be created"

did i miss something

Comment: What kind of recorder is it? VHS or Beta?

Comment: What?!? Please elaborate on that..

Comment: Maybe the tape is jammed. Used to happen to me all the time.

Comment: @Pekka -- it's kinescope

Comment: @Little hahaha! But I don't think so: a Kinescope recorder is unlikely to give such a verbose error message. It would take a modern recorder with an LCD display for that :)

Comment: i understand my question is very funny but i still waiting for answer

Comment: until one month i used qtp that have the option to record the test play, i am new in team system and i create an automatic test with test project - in the test setting in data and diagnostic i can choose video recorder but it not working

Comment: @erezgi you should add some relevant tags to your question and explicitly mention the product you are working with. We're cracking jokes because in its current form, hardly anybody will find the question, or be able to provide an answer

Comment: i am using team system 2010 ultimate version i open atest project record some action and then i enter the local test setting under data and diagnostic tab i check the video recorder option  after this i run the test and as i read it should record the the action i play but i got the error i said before

Answer (score 0):

Install Service Pack 1: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691

Install Expression Encoder 4: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18974

Try again and good luck!

Source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/vsautotest/thread/de112116-9421-4d20-8e4b-6821ce3845e3